# Working with H2 database from C#

Tags: c#, h2

I am able to connect to H2 database from my C# application with the help of below mentioned URL

http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html#microsoft_dot_net

```
org.h2.Driver.load();
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:~/test", "sa", "sa");
Statement stat = conn.createStatement();

//Working
ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("SELECT 'Hello World'");
while (rs.next())
{
    Console.WriteLine(rs.getString(1));
}

//Not Working
ResultSet rs1 = stat.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM TEST");
while (rs1.next())
{
    Console.WriteLine(rs1.getString(1));
}
```

I have changed the code "SELECT 'Hello World'" to "SELECT * FROM TEST" where "TEST" is the table name.
I am getting table not found error. But the table is present in H2 database.

**EDIT**
@ Nick Bull- Thank you so much for your help. Due to some reason the table created in "H2 console" is not accessible through c# code. I have tried with your logic, creating the table from C# code, it worked!!. But it is not showing in H2 console.

One more thing, "executeQuery" did not work for me to create the new table, I used "executeUpdate" (for someone it may help)

Answer (score 0):

I've used h2 a lot with Java. I think that the reason you can access the table in c# when you've created it in c# is because the database you are looking at is a different one to the one you're looking at in the console. Maybe recheck your connection string (in both c# and the console).

Databases are created if they don't exist by default by the h2 driver.